# Slow results from view query

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization, sql-view

My company has a view that we feed some reports through. I was presented with the issue that it was timing out by one of the managers who uses the report. After some investigation, I found it was taking 5 minutes to return 93,000 records from the stored procedure, and 3 minutes to return 68,000 records doing a select statement from the view with 1 where clause added (for year specification).

After running the select with the execution plan turned on, I went from 3 minutes to 16 seconds on the 68,000 records by adding an index that was missing. Is still far too slow for me to be okay with as this shouldn't take more than a second or 2.

Execution plan has 84% cost in my clustered index scan. Found another question here asking about how they can reduce that and tried the solution but it had no effect for me. I am not a DBA but a asp.net developer so I do not know the small details of indexing and optimizing.

The query is not doing a select * as others have suggested not to do as seen below:

```
SELECT 
    [Customer_Type]
    ,[Customer]
    ,[Unit_Number]
    ,[Cert_Number]
    ,[Effective_Date]
    ,[Expiration_Date]
    ,[Coverage]
    ,[CoveragePercentThefts]
    ,[Amount]
    ,[Facility_Name]
    ,[Facility_Policy_Number]
    ,[Accounting_Period]
    ,[Entry_Date]
    ,[Entry_Month]
    ,[Entry_Year]
    ,[FTD]
    ,[Month_FTD]
    ,[Year_FTD]
    ,[Entry_By]
    ,[Net_payment]
    ,[transaction_code]
    ,[Facility_Address]
    ,[Facility_City]
    ,[Facility_State]
    ,[Full_Name]
    ,[CalculatedNet]
    ,[PctTenantsInsured]
FROM 
    [Policy_Tracking].[dbo].[vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4]
WHERE
    Year_FTD = '2016'
```

Would anyone mind helping me get this down to a better number? I appreciate the help.

**EDIT:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4]
AS
    SELECT        
        dbo.Customer_Types.Customer_Type, 
        CASE 
           WHEN Customer_Types.Customer_Type = 'I' 
              THEN CUSTOMERS.First_Name + ' ' +     CUSTOMERS.Last_Name 
           WHEN Customer_Types.Customer_Type = 'O' 
                AND CUSTOMERS.Organization_Name > '' 
              THEN CUSTOMERS.Organization_Name 
           ELSE CUSTOMERS.First_Name + ' ' + CUSTOMERS.Last_Name 
        END AS Customer, 
        dbo.POLICYS.Unit_Number, dbo.POLICYS.Cert_Number, 
        dbo.POLICYS.Effective_Date, dbo.POLICYS.Expiration_Date, 
        dbo.Coverages.Coverage, dbo.CoveragePercentThefts.Description AS CoveragePercentThefts, 
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Amount, dbo.FACILITYS.Facility_Name, 
        dbo.FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number, 
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Accounting_Period, 
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Mod_Date AS Entry_Date, 
        MONTH(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Mod_Date) AS Entry_Month, 
        YEAR(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Mod_Date) AS Entry_Year, 
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Transaction_Date AS FTD, 
        MONTH(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Transaction_Date) AS Month_FTD, 
        YEAR(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Transaction_Date) AS Year_FTD, 
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Mod_ID AS Entry_By, 
        dbo.siteLink_Statement.dcNetPayment AS Net_payment, 
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Payment_Tran_Code_ID AS transaction_code, 
        dbo.FACILITYS.Address AS Facility_Address, 
        dbo.FACILITYS.City AS Facility_City, dbo.FACILITYS.State AS Facility_State, 
        dbo.CUSTOMERS.Full_Name, 
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Amount - dbo.FACILITYS.Commission_Rate * .01 * dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Amount AS CalculatedNet, 
        dbo.siteLink_Statement.dcPctTenantsInsured AS PctTenantsInsured
    FROM            
        dbo.Customer_Types 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.CUSTOMERS ON dbo.Customer_Types.ID = dbo.CUSTOMERS.Customer_Type_ID 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Policy_Facility_Customer 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.POLICYS ON dbo.Policy_Facility_Customer.Cert_Number = dbo.POLICYS.Cert_Number 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.FACILITYS ON dbo.POLICYS.Facility_Policy_Number = dbo.FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number 
                      AND dbo.Policy_Facility_Customer.Facility_ID = dbo.FACILITYS.ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Coverages ON dbo.POLICYS.Coverage_ID = dbo.Coverages.ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.CoveragePercentThefts ON dbo.POLICYS.Coverage_Percent_Theft_ID = dbo.CoveragePercentThefts.ID 
        ON dbo.CUSTOMERS.ID = dbo.Policy_Facility_Customer.Customer_ID 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions ON dbo.POLICYS.Cert_Number = dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Cert_Number 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.siteLink_Statement ON dbo.FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number = dbo.siteLink_Statement.SSFNumber 
                               AND MONTH(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Accounting_Period) = MONTH(DATEADD(m, - 1, dbo.siteLink_Statement.zCreationDate)) 
                               AND YEAR(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Accounting_Period) = YEAR(DATEADD(m, - 1, dbo.siteLink_Statement.zCreationDate))
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
     NumPanes = 4
     Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
     NumPanes = 3
     Configuration = "(H (1[34] 4[49] 3) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
     NumPanes = 3
     Configuration = "(H (1[50] 2[25] 3) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
     NumPanes = 3
     Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
     NumPanes = 2
     Configuration = "(H (1[56] 3) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
     NumPanes = 2
     Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
     NumPanes = 2
     Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
     NumPanes = 1
     Configuration = "(V (3))"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
     NumPanes = 3
     Configuration = "(H (1[15] 4[76] 2) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
     NumPanes = 2
     Configuration = "(H (1[28] 4) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
     NumPanes = 2
     Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
     NumPanes = 2
     Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
     NumPanes = 1
     Configuration = "(H (1) )"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
     NumPanes = 1
     Configuration = "(V (4))"
  End
  Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
     NumPanes = 1
     Configuration = "(V (2))"
  End
  ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
  Begin Origin = 
     Top = -100
     Left = 0
  End
  Begin Tables = 
     Begin Table = "Customer_Types"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 20
           Left = 680
           Bottom = 128
           Right = 836
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
     Begin Table = "CUSTOMERS"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 20
           Left = 446
           Bottom = 128
           Right = 620
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 6
     End
     Begin Table = "Policy_Facility_Customer"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 22
           Left = 40
           Bottom = 130
           Right = 191
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
     Begin Table = "POLICYS"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 38
           Left = 387
           Bottom = 146
           Right = 606
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
     Begin Table = "FACILITYS"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 188
           Left = 164
           Bottom = 296
           Right = 353
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
     Begin Table = "Coverages"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 155
           Left = 639
           Bottom = 263
           Right = 790
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
     Begin Table = "CoveragePercentThefts"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 330
           Left = 38
           Bottom = 438
           Right = 240
  ' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane2', @value=N'          End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
     Begin Table = "PAYMENTS_Transactions"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 432
           Left = 484
           Bottom = 540
           Right = 682
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
     Begin Table = "siteLink_Statement"
        Begin Extent = 
           Top = 240
           Left = 1076
           Bottom = 369
           Right = 1276
        End
        DisplayFlags = 280
        TopColumn = 0
     End
  End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
      Begin ColumnWidths = 20
     Width = 284
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
     Width = 1500
  End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 11
     Column = 19890
     Alias = 1410
     Table = 1500
     Output = 720
     Append = 1400
     NewValue = 1170
     SortType = 1350
     SortOrder = 1410
     GroupBy = 1350
     Filter = 1350
     Or = 1350
     Or = 1350
     Or = 1350
  End
   End
End
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value=2 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4'
GO
```

Comment: This view is quite simple.  No doubt the actual performance problem is in `vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for your prompt reply.  What or where do you suggest I look within the View?

Comment: Posting the definition of vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4 would help, as would the execution plan.

Comment: @ggiaquin show us view definition => vw_Facility_Detail_Report_V4

Comment: @Dejan I believe this is what you are looking for.  If not Please let me know

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: That mix of right, left, and inner joins is a headache.

Comment: @SqlZim tell me about it.... unfortunately this beast was created before I was hired here and the person who designed is no longer here....

Comment: your join condition for  `dbo.Policy_Facility_Customer` somehow ended up under the left join of `dbo.CoveragePercentThefts`

Comment: @SqlZim It is possible that the spacing may also be due to me trying to fit it into the code sample box.  I had to add spaces at the start of many lines in order for it to be recognized as part of the code sample.

Comment: @ggiaquin try not to use funtions like MONTH,YEAR OR DATEADD while joining tables it can neutralize index. Check if you have index created on the columns that participate in joining.

Comment: You need a **Calendar** table or **Date** Dimension.  - [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
 - [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
 - [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: @ggiaquin here is a reformat of your query with reorganized joins and aliases: http://pastebin.com/nanwN5kK

Answer (score 0):

If you can refactor this view that would be the best solution. If not you have few option to do.

1. [What makes a SQL statement sargable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

Your this part of query is not `sargable`

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.siteLink_Statement ON dbo.FACILITYS.Facility_Policy_Number = dbo.siteLink_Statement.SSFNumber 
   AND MONTH(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Accounting_Period) = MONTH(DATEADD(m, - 1, dbo.siteLink_Statement.zCreationDate)) 
   AND    YEAR(dbo.PAYMENTS_Transactions.Accounting_Period) = YEAR(DATEADD(m, - 1, dbo.siteLink_Statement.zCreationDate))
```

2. Make sure all `JOINs Column` should be indexed.
3. If its possible then you can make the selected columns to be included as Covering Index to avoid Key Lookup.  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/